# Package php5-json breaks firephp

Tags: debian, php, firefox, json

#### Background

Recently I upgraded php to version 5.5. Within this upgrade module for json was moved out from php5 package into a new package php5-json. So I installed it.

**Now the connection with firephp (and firebug).**
Before sending, firephp::log encodes the variable with json_encode.
There might occur an issue with json_encode. The json_encode may fail to encode the input variable. This might happen in a string with unencoded unicode or a string with some ill encoded characters.

#### Behaviour in previous version of php

- In firebug instead of the value with the wrong coding white space appears.
- After the wrong value firebug continues to display next values which arrived from firephp.

#### Behaviour with separate php5-json

- When the ill encoded value arrives to firebug, following error message appears:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
>      chrome://firephp/content/lib/renderer.js
>      Line 159
>
> After this listing logs from firephp stops.
>
> #### Question

I understand that there was an 'unexpected character'. But I'd just like to move on and see the following messages. Not stop on the first unexpected character.
What shall I do to solve the issue? Or at least get back to the previous bevior?

#### Software versions:

- Debian testing jessie
- Linux host 3.10-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.10.5-1 (2013-08-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
- php5 5.5.1+dfsg-2
- php5-json 1.3.1+dfsg-1
- iceweasel 22.0
- FirePHPCore-0.3.2
- Firebug 1.11.4
- Firephp 0.7.2

#### Edit:

I also can see in Firebug header X-Wf-1-1-1-2:

> [{"Type":"LOG","Label":"$someVar","File":"/home/GIT/www/some/path/someFile.php","Line":"156"},]

Which **does** miss the value part and thus is **not valid JSON**, which is why the rendering fails.

The header with the correct message, which gets printed:

> [{"Type":"LOG","Label":"POST data","File":"/home/GIT/www/some/path/someFile.php","Line":"22"},{"data":{"myarray":["117"]},"getA":"true","getB":"true"}]

#### Edit2:

I submitted this as a bug in Debian [719942](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=719942). But it doesn't seem that someone is willing to have a look at it :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Background:

There is a licensing [conflict](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63520) with Linux distributions over a clause in [Crockford's](http://crockford.com/) [license](http://www.json.org/license.html) which states:
      *The Software shall be used for Good, not Evil.*
This does not agree with the Free Software Foundation’s (FSF) freedom 0:
      *The freedom to run the program for any purpose.* ([source](http://iteration99.com/2013/php-json-licensing-and-php-5-5/))

The solution to it shall be a newly written library [pecl-json-c](https://github.com/remicollet/pecl-json-c) packaged as php5-json. The newly used json library doesn't seem to be compatible with [firephp](http://www.firephp.org/). But if you will use software for Good, not Evil, you might want to restore the original Crockford's library.

#### Steps to restore the Crockford's library

1) Get the original [json 1.2.1](http://pecl.php.net/package/json/1.2.1) library and unzip it.
2) Install php5-dev (in Debian `sudo apt-get install php5-dev`) which comes with `phpize` tool. (source: [How to create PHP extensions](http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/07/07/how-to-create-php-extensions-in-c-part-i-adding-simple-function/)).
3) As [jacekk](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61479) suggests you need to replace one occurrence of `function_entry` in `json.c` with `zend_function_entry`.
4) As [Star](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10188130/775066) suggests you need to replace `ZVAL_DELREF` with `Z_DELREF_P` in three places in file `JSON_parser.c`.
5) Then you change directory to the json-1.2.1 and run

```
phpize
./configure
make
```

6) Unfortunatelly you can't remove the package php5-json, because it will take with it the whole php. Instead you need to locate the library json.so (`dpkg -L php5-json | grep json.so` will do).
7) As the root replace the Remi's json.so with Crockford's json.so you just compiled.

#### Drawbacks

With the next upgrade of php5-json you'll get back Remi's library.
You are now using non-free software.
You are messing-up with your system.
Some people claim that the Remi's library has more features, which is probably true, because the Crockford's library is from 2005.

Comment: This [bugreport](https://code.google.com/p/firephp/issues/detail?id=166) links to firephp 0.3.3 which solves the firephp issue.